# Javascript combine regex with length check

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following check in my Javascript code.

```
if(someValueToCheck.replace(/[^0-9]/g,"").length>13){
    return "Invalid"
}
```

My question is if it is possible to combine this into a single regex. I am planning to plug that regex directly to a ember-cp-validations library using something like below;

```
    validations['my-custom-regex'] = {
      'with': myfield.regex, //Consolidated regex from above
      'allowBlank': true,
      'message': message
   };
```

Comment: Can you elaborate your logic in English please? Is "non-digit string greater than 13 length" a proper translation?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Yes, that is exactly right

Comment: Also, are you just interested in validation or data correction as well? You have data correction with your JS but the validator plugin doesn't sound like it will correct the data.

Comment: I just want to validate the data...No correction needed

Comment: `\D{14,}` would do it.

Comment: Ok...but what about this part someValueToCheck.replace(/[^0-9]/g,"")....how can we club this with the length check?

Comment: `{14,}` is the length check

Comment: Hmm...ok...and \D would just consider the digits (ignoring any other characters like say -(MINUS)/.(DOT)/(COMMA), etc

Comment: `\D` is the same as `[^0-9]`. If you're really new to regex then I recommend checking out https://regex101.com/ because it will tell you the literal meaning of the syntax

Comment: In plain English my regex says "require 14 or more non-digits". However, I do have to correct myself by adding start and end anchors: `^\D{14,}$`

Comment: Thanks  a lot ....Actually in my case, if "only digits" are greater than 13 length, then it should be invalid...So assume that is what the above regex would help